# Android: Run thread in background even when the app was closed by the user

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send a http request to my server in the background after I closed the app. But the thread is always being killed. I already tried Workmanager, AlarmManager and BackgroundService. I have been searching in the internet for solutions for the last weeks and I couldn't find any solutions working in newer API's and without a ForegroundService which has to display a notification while running.

Starting AlarmManager:

```java
        //NotificationAlarm is the class implementing BroadcastReceiver
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ALARM_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pendingIntent);
```

Until about Android 6 the AlarmManager works to me. However in latest versions it keeps getting closed.

I used the following tutorial as template for BackgroundServices but it still did not work: https://medium.com/@raziaranisandhu/create-services-never-stop-in-android-b5dcfc5fb4b2

I'm Looking forward to an answer.

Comment: Hi Intex32, Welcome to stackoverflow . Please show us what you have tried before then only someone can give some solution. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever tried ForegroundService?...
you can create class extended as service btw, just add the intent filter on the manifest.
Example from friend's class.

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);

    //do heavy work on a background thread


    //stopSelf();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

And start it as
  `startForegroundService(context,ForegroundService.class);`

There is a lot of options
(Foreground service will start a notification until its dead)

Comment: No I didn't try to use a ForegroundService because I don't want my App to display all the time a notification.

Comment: JobScheduler?... thats another option, and also u can try making bus, but i dont really know at all how to use it, there's a lot of libraries about

Comment: Do you know whether it gets killed when the app is closed by the user?

Comment: Nope, they're alive even when the app is closed from the taskbar, they'll get closed only when the app crash or when u stop them

Comment: I have just tested it and it seems to work on an emulator. The AlarmMangager worked on the emulators too but not on real devices. I will try it out on an API 28 device in the next few days cause I don't have one currently.

Comment: NO, it is not working on a real API 28 device although it works on the emulator! Have you got any other ideas?

Comment: did you ever asked for permissions?...
you are working with threads on the background, those threads have another security arquitecture.
if the request from the main question its just plain text, use asynctask, and when its over, stop the entry app